# C - Incompatible Pointer Type

Tags: c, pointers, struct, initialization, incompatibletypeerror

Why does the following code give warnings?

```
int main(void)
{
    struct {int x; int y;} test = {42, 1337};
    struct {int x; int y;} *test_ptr = &test;
}
```

Results:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         struct {int x; int y;} *test_ptr = &test;
                                            ^
```

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler's answer is correct. Any conversion between different types of pointers will throw that warning. Unfortunately since both structs are unnamed and distinct, you cannot cast between them. That's why you should declare your structures beforehand.

Comment: In addition to other answers, it's worth noticing that it is possible to get rid of the warning. Just make an intermediate cast to `void*`: `struct {int x; int y;} *test_ptr = (void*)&test;`

Comment: If you want them to be the same type, define the type *once*.

Comment: @Radnyx: It's not quite that simple. Conversions between *incompatible* pointer types are (in most but not all cases) a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic. (gcc issues a warning by default, which is valid, but it could be a fatal error). Types can be compatible without being the same type; also `void*` and, for example, `int*` are incompatible, but may be assigned to each other (there's an implicit conversion).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

They're two anonymous structure types (they neither have a tag).  All such structure types (in a single translation unit) are distinct — they're never the same type.  Add a tag!

The relevant sentence in the standard is in §6.7.2.1 **Structure and union specifiers**:

> ¶8 The presence of a *struct-declaration-list* in a *struct-or-union-specifier* declares a new type,
>   within a translation unit.

The *struct-declaration-list* refers to the material between `{` and `}` in the type.

That means that in your code, there are two separate types, one for each `struct { … }`.  The two types are separate; you cannot officially assign a value of one type to the other, nor create pointers, etc.  In fact, you can't reference those types again after the semicolon.

That means you could have:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct {int x; int y;} test = {42, 1337}, *tp = &test;
    struct {int x; int y;} result, *result_ptr;
    result_ptr = &result;
    …
}
```

Now `test` and `tp` refer to the same type (one a structure, one a pointer to the structure), and similarly `result` and `result_ptr` refer to the same type, and the initializations and assignments are fine, but the two types are different.  It's not clear that you create a compound literal of either type — you'd have to write `(struct {int x; int y;}){.y = 9, .x = 8}`, but the presence of the *struct-declaration-list* means that is another new type.

As noted in the comments, there is also section §6.2.7 **Compatible type and composite type**, which says:

> ¶1 … Moreover, two structure,
>   union, or enumerated types declared in separate translation units are compatible if their
>   tags and members satisfy the following requirements: If one is declared with a tag, the
>   other shall be declared with the same tag. If both are completed anywhere within their
>   respective translation units, then the following additional requirements apply: there shall
>   be a one-to-one correspondence between their members such that each pair of
>   corresponding members are declared with compatible types; if one member of the pair is
>   declared with an alignment specifier, the other is declared with an equivalent alignment
>   specifier; and if one member of the pair is declared with a name, the other is declared
>   with the same name. For two structures, corresponding members shall be declared in the
>   same order. For two structures or unions, corresponding bit-fields shall have the same
>   widths.

Roughly speaking, that says that if the definitions of the types in the two translation units (think 'source files' plus included headers) are the same, then they refer to the same type.  Thank goodness for that!  Otherwise, you couldn't have the standard I/O library working, amongst other minor details.

Comment: That is not entirely true, two anonymous structs defined in different translation units can be made compatible.

Comment: @2501: Agreed (§6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type)...I'm trying to find where the standard says what I say within a single TU.

Answer (score 13):

Variables `&test` and `test_ptr`, which are anonymous structs, have different types.

Anonymous structs defined in the same translation unit are never compatible types<sup>1</sup> as the Standard doesn't define compatibility for two structure type definitions in the same translation unit.

To have your code compile, you could do:

```
struct {int x; int y;} test = {42, 1337} , *test_ptr;
test_ptr = &test;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: ISO:IEC 9899:201X 6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type 1)
Two types have compatible type if their types are the same. Additional rules for determining whether two types are compatible are described in 6.7.2 for type specifiers, in 6.7.3 for type qualifiers, and in 6.7.6 for declarators. **Moreover, two structure, union, or enumerated types declared in separate translation units are compatible** if their tags and members satisfy the following requirements: If one is declared with a tag, the other shall be declared with the same tag. If both are completed anywhere within their respective translation units, then the following additional requirements apply: there shall be a one-to-one correspondence between their members such that each pair of corresponding members are declared with compatible types; if one member of the pair is declared with an alignment specifier, the other is declared with an equivalent alignment specifier; and if one member of the pair is declared with a name, the other is declared with the same name. For two structures, corresponding members shall be declared in the same order. For two structures or unions, corresponding bit-fields shall have the same widths. For two enumerations, corresponding members shall have the same values.

Comment: That seems to say that it should work, no? Neither has a tag and their members are the same.

Comment: @zneak Notice the first bolded quote: separate translation units.

Comment: Try §6.7.2.1 ¶8 for the different types within a single TU.

Comment: I think the formatting should be the way I edited it. It reads much better (IMO).

Comment: @black I agree that the reference should be at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

C was originally designed so that pointers to structures with partially- or totally-identical layouts could be used interchangeably to access the common portions, and versions of the language before C89 which implemented individual namespaces for structure members generally retained the ability to use the pointers interchangeably with the aid of typecasts, conversions through void, etc.  While it would be legal for compilers to have insert different amounts of padding before different sizes of array, most compilers specify that they perform layout without doing so, meaning that one could easily write a function which would accept a pointer to either of the following objects, or anything else declared similarly (of size 4, 5, 24601, etc.)

```
struct { int size; int foo[2]; } my_two_foos = {2, {1,2} };
struct { int size; int foo[3]; } my_three_foos = {3, {4,5,6} };
```

Since implementations were not required to offer any guarantees about layout that would make such constructs indispensable, the authors of the Standard declined to mandate that compilers recognize any concept of layout compatibility, since those compilers where such an ability would be indispensable (e.g. those where structures like the above would be laid out in consistent fashion) already supported it, and there was no reason to believe they wouldn't continue to do so whether or not the Standard mandated it.  The driving factor for whether a feature or guarantee should be mandated was not whether the costs would be outweighed the benefits on platforms that could cheaply and easily support that feature or guarantee, but whether the costs on platforms where support would be most expensive and minimally useful would be outweighed by the benefits *on those same platforms*.

Unfortunately, compiler writers have lost sight of the fact that the Standard only defines what is necessary for an implementation to be a "compliant" and does not define what features make something a good a compiler for a given platform, and as a consequence they have become increasingly aggressive at finding excuses to ignore precedents on platforms where behaviors had for decades been supported at minimal cost.  As a consequence, code which relies upon behaviors that used to be commonplace may only work correctly if one uses compiler options like `-fno-strict-aliasing` which disable far more optimziations than would have been necessary when using a less-aggressive compiler.